# Duplicate migrations listed after generating config for a migrate-upgrade

Tags: 8, migrations

TL;DR - I'm trying to build a migration - despite starting from scratch each time, the migrations from my D7 site are duplicated in the drush migrate-status output.

e.g.

- d7_node:contact (in the 'default' group)
- upgrade_d7_node_contact (in the 'migrate_drupal_7' group)

*and sometimes even recursively:*

- upgrade_upgrade_d7_node_contact

This is repeated for every migration.

**Questions:**

- Firstly, what's going on with the groups? There are no migrations listed under "default" in the UI, but an entire duplicate set when I use `drush migrate-status`.  What's the default group **for** in this case? Can I ignore it?
- That default group includes a bunch of d6_ migrations. Is that normal when you've generated migrations from a D7 legacy site? None are listed in migrate_drupal_7 or the *'Exporting x as y'* output of migrate-upgrade, and obviously many will simply fail with an SQL error because the D6 table structure is different.
- As well as resetting the DB before I start (I've verified there are no migrate_plus.migration config entries) and rebuilding the cache (memcached in this case) do I need to be resetting anything else? Does it point to a problem with the source DB?

---

**Specifics:**

I'm doing a D7-D8 upgrade, using `migrate-upgrade` to generate the configuration first so I can then use `migrate-manifest` to run selected migrations.

As is to be expected, this involves multiple attempts, so I have a clean DB (no content but the correct modules) which I reset to each time:

```
mysqladmin drop foo
mysqladmin create foo
drush sql:cli < my-clean-d8-db.sql
drush cr
```

At this stage, `/admin/structure/migrate` just has an empty Default group.

```
drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-key=migrate --legacy-root=/Users/me/Sites/foo --configure-only
```

This output of this looks sensible - to use one migration as an example:

```
Exporting d7_node:contact as upgrade_d7_node_contact
```